# Call a LIST<DOUBLE> inside button1 click event into button2 click event in c#

Tags: c#, buttonclick

I have two buttons in my C# windows form application. Button1 and Button2.
i want to use a variable and a list calculated in Button1's event as an input variable in Button2's event. how can I do that? Example:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   int a;
   // some steps 
   // after these steps, assume a gets the value of 5 so a = 5 at this point.
// also there is a list which gets its values after these steps
List<double> parameterValues = new List<double> { 
                i.GetDouble(), S.GetDouble(), L.GetDouble(),B.GetDouble()                   
};
}
```

Here is the code for button2 event, in this I want to be able to use the value of a calculated in button1's code.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   int b = a + 5;
// some code to call the list as well
}
```

Comment: Make `a` a global variable (`public int a`) and instantiate it outside of `button1_Click()`.

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Do I Use A Variable In One Method If It Was Declared In A Different Method? C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644496/how-do-i-use-a-variable-in-one-method-if-it-was-declared-in-a-different-method)

Comment: Thanks, could u also suggest something for the list of doubles as well please.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make int a global in order to use it in both buttons.

```
public int a;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
  a = 5;
// some steps 
// after these steps, assume a gets the value of 5 so a = 5 at this point.
}



private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   int b = a + 5;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, could u kindly suggest somehting fo rthe list as well .

Answer (score 0):

You have a scope issue currently.  The value you want to use inside button click 2 must be at least modular to the forms class in order to use in both methods.   In this example, "outerValue" is modular and can be accessed by both.   Have a read through this article to get a better overview of variable scope.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int outerValue = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int a = 5;
        outerValue = a + 5;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int b = outerValue + 5;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works for the int datatypes. I also have the following element which is genereated after all those steps in button1: 

    List<double> parameterValues = new List<double> { 
                    i.GetDouble(), S.GetDouble(), L.GetDouble(),B.GetDouble(), 
    TC.GetDouble(),
                    TTc, TTj.GetDouble(),TCBa.GetDouble(),TCBb, TCBc.GetDouble(), 
    TCBd.GetDouble() 
                        };

I am not sure how to handle lists becuase if I declare the list (listname) globally I cannot add values in the way i have added in the code baove.

Comment: Thanks, could u kindly suggest something for the list as well .

Comment: To add items to a list outside of constructor initialization, you would need to use the methods that exist on the list class.   Look at the Add method first....it is the most common, but there are others that exist as well if you want to insert a range or insert an item at a specific location.   For example, parameterValues.Add(i.GetDouble());

Comment: Also, as a side note, the word global has been used in this post several times and it is being used incorrectly in nearly every case.  Global variables would be accessible beyond the scope of the form's class.  Modular variables are only scoped to the class.  99.99999% of the time you want to avoid global variables.